# How to get variable from the process importing my script?

Tags: python, python-import

So, `A.py` imports `B.py`, but `B.py` needs to access a variable from `A.py`. How would I go about doing this? So far, I've tried:

```
import B
B.variable=4
```

and

```
#A.py
import B
B.setvar(4)
```

```
#B.py
def setvar(int_):
    global variable
    variable=int_
```

`A.py` knows the value of `variable`, but `B.py` does not. `B.py` needs access to `variable`, which is stored in `A.py`.

Comment: if something in `B.py` needs a variable from `A.py` it should either be a part of `A.py` or it should be passed as a parameter in `A.py`.

Comment: @Cresht Yes, ```variable``` is part of ```A.py```. ```B.py``` needs to access it.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC it would (if the two .py are in the same directory)

```
from WeatherUI import  *
from SWDriver import  *
WeatherUI.set_driver(temp) #This is just an example of accessing the temp variable from the SWDriver.py
while True:
    SWDriver.update()
    WeatherUI.update()
```

This should give you access to all the variables/functions/classes from b in another .py

Comment: I think that you misunderstand. ```B.py``` needs a variable from ```A.py```, not the other way around.

Comment: You could just change B to A in the B.py then you would have access to the A.py variables...or do I still misunderstand?

Comment: In reality this is a simplified version of my problem. ```A.py``` is actually ```MAIN.py```, ```B.py``` is ```WeatherUI.py```, and there is a third script: ```SWDriver.py```. ```MAIN.py``` helps ```WeatherUI.py``` and ```SWDriver.py``` to communicate. For more information, see my GitHub repository: https://github.com/UxuginPython/SkyWeather/tree/1.0.0

Comment: Ok I updated my code so based on your code MAIN.py will have access to all the variables from the other 2 .py

Comment: I'm sorry - I was unclear. The ```driver``` variable in ```WeatherUI.py``` needs to be set to the imported object of ```SWDriver.py``` such that it could be accessed as a module. This is the job of ```MAIN.py```.